# Why are cells displayed one on top of the other?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

With this code, when I alternate the boxes displayed in the input parameters as in this screenshot, the rows of the 2 columns are superimposed as in this screenshot.

[image]
[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator('TEST', overlay=true)


b1 = input.bool(false, '1', inline='b1'), B1 = input.bool(false, '1', inline='b1')
b2 = input.bool(false, '2', inline='b2'), B2 = input.bool(false, '2', inline='b2')
b3 = input.bool(false, '3', inline='b3'), B3 = input.bool(false, '3', inline='b3')
b4 = input.bool(false, '4', inline='b4'), B4 = input.bool(false, '4', inline='b4')
b5 = input.bool(false, '5', inline='b5'), B5 = input.bool(false, '5', inline='b5')
b6 = input.bool(false, '6', inline='b6'), B6 = input.bool(false, '6', inline='b6')
b7 = input.bool(false, '7', inline='b7'), B7 = input.bool(false, '7', inline='b7')
b8 = input.bool(false, '8', inline='b8'), B8 = input.bool(false, '8', inline='b8')
b9 = input.bool(false, '9', inline='b9'), B9 = input.bool(false, '9', inline='b9')


bool1 = array.from(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9)
bool2 = array.from(B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9)

string = array.from('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

var tab = table.new(position=position.top_right, columns=2, rows=10)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(tab, 0, 0, text='Col0', text_size=size.large, bgcolor=color.new(color.gray,80), text_color=color.white)
    table.cell(tab, 1, 0, text='Col1', text_size=size.large, bgcolor=color.new(color.gray,80), text_color=color.white)

if barstate.isrealtime
    for i = 0 to array.size(bool1) - 1 by 1
        if array.get(bool1, i)
            table.cell(tab, 0, i+1, text=str.tostring(array.get(string, i)), text_color=color.blue, bgcolor=color.new(color.blue,80))

    for i = 0 to array.size(bool2) - 1 by 1
        if array.get(bool2, i)
            table.cell(tab, 1, i+1, text=str.tostring(array.get(string, i)), text_color=color.blue, bgcolor=color.new(color.blue,80))
```

I'd like to know if you know a solution so that the display is not superimposed without using array.push() to store them in a new array and array.get() to get the contents of this new array.

Why am I trying to do this? Because I'm trying to eliminate the step that uses array.push() and array.get() to make the script faster... What do you think?

Comment: What would be your real use-case? If you stick with input parameters your execution on each bar is redundant since their values won't change. If you'll work with "real" values instead, the execution in real time for this small loop is still not a problem, your tests on historical data could be somewhat slower at most, though I wouldn't think that could be your bottleneck in your script.

Comment: Thank you for responding.. but sorry I didn't understand your response